# How to update model in DataSource window?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I use DataGridView, and object model as datasource. I edited model, that is used by DataGridView, but when I try to add new column  is based on model, I can not see that. But it exists in model like as:

```
public string status { get; set; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the binding data source and then readd it. That will force the refresh and you will see your new property.